# Consistency failure in amounts received

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, daemon, monero-wallet-rpc

When I tried to send the amount from my wallet. monero-wallet-rpc throws `2018-10-20 10:58:22.492     7f6906cab780        WARN    global  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1511     Consistency failure in amounts received
2018-10-20 10:58:22.492     7f6906cab780        WARN    global  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1512     Check transaction <629360cd53ead8d7668962d58b2abd026b401e66ecfcc2c49a0e51d
81bf26b6a>`

Any solution please,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please file a bug on https://github.com/monero-project/monero, with all the information about what you are doing, as well as the exact version of the monero code you're running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you send funds from your wallet back to that same wallet? This warning message might reflect an inability, when observing the blockchain, to distinguish between the amount sent and the change.

When you send a transaction back to yourself, you'll create two outputs destined for your own wallet. One will be the "amount sent", and the other will be "change". Change is generated because the amount you're sending to yourself probably isn't the exact same amount as the output you're spending (especially after fees are deducted). Since both outputs are sent back to you, it's hard to later distinguish between the amount sent and the change amount, since they are both outputs indistinguishably addressed to you.

Comment: Yes, I am sending the amount within wallet by creating two different account.